# How to access and overwrite XML data using SimpleXML?

Tags: xml, simplexml

I have a XML file : photo.xml which looks like this.

```
       <?xml version="1.0" ?> 
       - <users>
           - <uploader ID="11">
             <Name>moz</Name> 
             <Photos_Uploaded>2</Photos_Uploaded> 
           </uploader>

         </users>
```

So each time the user moz uploads a new photo, the XML file should increment photos_uploaded by 1. I have already done this with PHP.

What i am asking is how do i use SimpleXML to access the photo.xml and modify the data to reflect the change and save it?

regards

Edit:

I tried this but it did not work.

```
    $xml_Doc = new DOMDocument();
    $xml_Doc->load('photo.xml');


        $statistics="SELECT firstname AS 'user', count( * ) AS 'num',member_id AS ID
        FROM members
        JOIN member_photo
        USING ( member_id )
        GROUP BY firstname ";
        $result= mysql_query($statistics);


    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $uploader=$xml->addChild('uploader');
    $uploader->addAttribute('ID',$row['ID']);
    $uploader->addChild('Name', $row['user']);
    $uploader->addChild('Photos_Uploaded', $row['num']);
    $xml->asXML('');

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can just do this, if i'm understanding your question correctly:

```
$xml_data = '<?xml version="1.0" ?><users><uploader ID="11"><Name>moz</Name><Photos_Uploaded>2</Photos_Uploaded></uploader></users>';
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml_data);
$xml->uploader->Photos_Uploaded = 3;
echo $xml->asXML();
```

this outputs:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><users><uploader ID="11"><Name>moz</Name><Photos_Uploaded>3</Photos_Uploaded></uploader></users>
```

i hope this helps :)

Comment: This looks right; there is no need to add a Photos_Uploaded child as in the question, since it already exists.

Comment: No you did not understand the question. I want to overwrite the whole XML file (photo.xml) with the new data.

Comment: you can overwrite the data, the value started with 2 and i re-wrote it to be 3 :)

Answer (score 0):

As of 2018 the way would be:

```
//load xml
$xml = simplexml_load_file('photo.xml');
// modifiy 
//your code..
// save it back
$xml->asXML('photo.xml');
```

source: http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.asxml.php